# Add manual salt with password to generate SHA1 in C

Tags: c, hash, openssl, sha1

I want to add a custom salt to generate SHA1 hash as:

```
 SHA1_Init(&sha_ctx);
  SHA1_Update(&sha_ctx, salt, strlen(salt));
  SHA1_Update(&sha_ctx, string, strlen(string));
  SHA1_Final(sha1_digest, &sha_ctx);
```

But the output is incorrect why?

```
Password: abcd
salt: 1234
output: e7d537e128158790157ea057bb883e0292a84930
```

Comment: What makes you think that the output is incorrect? What is the output? What output do you expect? Does it work the standard way (i.e. without trying to add a manual salt)? Please make a [mre].

Comment: I get the same output from `echo -n "1234abcd" |sha1sum`, so looks right to me.

Comment: What makes you think your output is incorrect? Your output looks correct to me: `e7d537e128158790157ea057bb883e0292a84930`. Check here: http://www.sha1-online.com/ with `1234abcd`. Are you sure the code you run is the code you show here? Maybe you should show a [mcve].